# Need help setting value for "is_staff" and "is_superuser" for Django LDAP authenticated users

Tags: django, ldap

I new to both Django and LDAP. I am creating a Django application with LDAP authentication as the login system. I am able to connect to the LDAP server and authenticate using a preexisting account from LDAP, which then populate my MySQL database *auth_user* table to have data row like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fUHhr.png):

So my question is how can I set the value for "is_staff" and "is_superuser" to be 1?

*-- LDAP setting inside settings.py --*

```
AUTH_LDAP_SERVER_URI = "ldap://ldap.m*****.com:389"
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_DN = ""
AUTH_LDAP_BIND_PASSWORD = ""
AUTH_LDAP_USER_SEARCH = LDAPSearch("o=m*****net", ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, "(uid=%(user)s)")

AUTH_LDAP_USER_ATTR_MAP = {
    "first_name": "givenName",
    "last_name": "sn",
    "email": "mail",
}

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'django_auth_ldap.backend.LDAPBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
    )

# logging
logger = logging.getLogger('django_auth_ldap')
logger.addHandler(logging.StreamHandler())
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
```

Answer (score 0):

The setting [`AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP`](https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#std:setting-AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP) can be used to match groups to the user flags

```
AUTH_LDAP_USER_FLAGS_BY_GROUP = {
    "is_active": "cn=active,ou=django,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
    "is_staff": "cn=staff,ou=django,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
    "is_superuser": "cn=superuser,ou=django,ou=groups,dc=example,dc=com",
}
```

Comment: Thank you for responding. I've tried that but I got this error: AUTH_LDAP_GROUP_TYPE must be an LDAPGroupType instance. Any idea how to solve this?

Comment: The example configuration is probably a good start, you may be able to just copy that setting from since it just searches on "cn" there https://django-auth-ldap.readthedocs.io/en/latest/example.html